# How to use *ngFor to concatenate two properties in optionLabel in p-dropdown options in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng

I have a requirement to concatenate two properties and show it in the optionLabel in the p-dropdown in Angular? I'm able to do it in mat-select but not in p-dropdown.

Any help to convert the below mat-select code to p-dropdown is appreciated.

```
<label for="Pricing Office ID"> Pricing Office ID</label>
<mat-select type="text" class="custom-mat-select" name="pricingOfficeID" formControlName="pricingOfficeID (selectionChange)="changePricingOfficeID()">
<mat-option *ngFor="let office of worldAreaSpecifcOffices" [value]="office.referenceId"> {{office.referenceId}} - {{office.officeName}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

worldAreaSpecifcOffices is the object which contain referenceId & OfficeName properties. I would like to concatenate those properties and show it in the optionLabel. referenceId will be mapped to optionValue. While loading the form I will be assigning the value to the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates inside the `p-dropdown` element.
Example:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="worldAreaSpecifcOffices" formControlName="pricingOfficeID" optionLabel="name">
    <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
        {{selectedOffice.referenceId}} - {{selectedOffice.officeName}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-office pTemplate="item">
        {{office.referenceId}} - {{office.officeName}}
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```